# equal padding around image inside a container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a multiple file upload system.File upload works fine.Problem arises when i've decided to show a preview div before file reading complete.For this purpose i create a container div inside for loop and tried to insert image in that container.Problem is that the image inside the container doesn't have equal padding around it.How to fix this problem?

```js
function handleDragOver(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
  document.getElementById('drop_zone').innerHTML = "";
}

function handleDragLeave() {
  document.getElementById('drop_zone').style.background = 'white';
}

function handleFileSelect(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

  for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
    if (i >= files.length) {
      break;
    }
    (function(file) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      var container = document.createElement('div');
      reader.onloadstart = function() {


        container.setAttribute('style', 'background:gray;text-align:center;padding:2px;width:100px;height:100px;margin:8px;float:left;border:1px solid gray;');
        document.getElementById('drop_zone').appendChild(container);

      };

      reader.onloadend = (function(myfile) {

        return function(event) {

          var img = new Image();
          img.src = event.target.result;
          img.width = 100;
          img.height = 100;
          container.style.background = 'white';
          container.style.width = '';
          container.style.height = '';
          container.appendChild(img);


        }

      })(file);


      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })(file);




  }


}

function handleFileUpload() {

  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);

}
handleFileUpload();
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone" style="width:95%;border:4px dotted gray;float:left;min-height:100px;text-align:center;line-height:100px;color:gray;font-size:25px;">
  Drop files here

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line-height of the #drop_zone is set to 100px which is causing the problem.

Set the line-height of the image to `line-height: 0;`

Comment: should i do this : img.style.lineHeight = 0+'px'; ? Seems it is not working

Comment: Like this: `img.style.lineHeight = "0";`

Comment: The image inherited the style of the parent since the line-height is not defined on a image by default.